# accessing data in multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this array

```
[  
   [  
      null,
      {  
         "1":{  
            "Name":"TEST ITEM 1",
            "Qty":1,
            "Price":1.99,
            "Desc":"Test Desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   {  
      "2":{  
         "Name":"TEST ITEM 2",
         "Qty":1,
         "Price":1.99,
         "Desc":"Test Desc"
      }
   }
]
```

Now i can't seem to get the data inside, what i need to do is just to loop through it all and get the data inside, but i can't seem to access the data.

I'm unsure if the structure of my array is right, i'm basically turning my array into json to store in my database then turning it back into json when i retrieve it from the database and using array_push to put data into it.

Any help?

Comment: could you post the structure of your array with var_dump()?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a normal PHP array and do you business logic that way and use the json_encode() function before storing it in the database?

You can play with the code [here](https://ideone.com/6HFhCt)

```
$php_array = array(
    "1" => array(
                "name"  => "test item 1",
                "qty"   => 1,
                "price" => 1.99,
                "desc"  => "test desc"
        ),
    "2" => array(
                "name"  => "test item 2",
                "qty"   => 1,
                "price" => 1.99,
                "desc"  => "test desc 2"

        )
);


foreach($php_array as $arr){
    foreach($arr as $level_two){
        echo $level_two; 
    }
}

$json_array = json_encode($php_array);
```